# API data and variable undefined

Tags: javascript, json

I'm parsing some data that I fetched, but some of the data in the `JSON` is not defined.

For example, a contact object can have `first_name`, `last_name`, and `job_title`, but sometimes `job_title` is not set.

To avoid my scripts crashing because of this undefined variable, I check to make sure the variable exists:

```
if (this.data[x]) {
 // do your thing
}
```

I have to put these checks all over the place and, on particularly large scripts, it makes my code difficult to follow.

Is there a better way to tell my code to keep running even if it hits an undefined variable? For example, if an undefined value is met anywhere in the path, return an empty string.

Below is an example of a situation where this would be helpful because I could cut back on all the `if`s:

```
var filtrate;
if (d.ContactValues) {
    filtrate = d.ContactValues.filter(function(o) {
        return o.RefContactMethod.key === 'office_phone';
    });

    if (filtrate.length > 0) {
        return filtrate[0].value;
    }

    //... additional if statements ...
}
```

**EDIT #1**

Just to keep you all posted, I ran some basic performance tests: http://jsperf.com/undefined-var-try-catch-and-other

I will run a more in-depth and real-world tests later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you parse the JSON, you can fill in the object with default values:

```
fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'job_title'];
for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    if (!(fields[i] in object)) {
        fields[i] = '';
    }
}
```

Another option would be to write your own `getProp` function:

```
function getProp(obj, property, default) {
    if (property in obj) {
        return obj[property];
    } else {
        return default;
    }
}
```

Then use `getProp(obj, 'job_title', '')` instead of `obj.job_title`.

This could be rewritten with `try/catch`, it might be more efficient that way:

```
function getProp(obj, property, default) {
    try {
        return obj[property];
    } catch (e) {
        return default;
    }
}
```

Comment: that would require me copying my whole API's data structure into my clientside... not sure this is a good idea.

Comment: I actually like your second option quite a bit. I was already doing something vaguely similar... though abstracting the variable existence verification is a nice idea.
In essence, this "could" be done with the try-catch blocks too, I suppose?

Comment: Yes, I've added that version.

Comment: lookin good! I'll do some benchmarks on my end to see what works fastest, but this is very much along the lines of what I needed! thx.

Comment: `obj[property]` will not throw if `obj` has no `property`.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [exception handling](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/trycatch.shtml):

```
try {
  // Do something that can throw an exception
} catch(err) {
  console.log('the error was ' + err);
  // set a default value, or whatever
}
```

This is exactly what exceptions are designed for (gracefully handling errors in a program and continuing smoothly).
If you want to catch the undefined variable and set it to a default value:

```
catch(e if e instanceof TypeError){
    if ( /'/.test( err.message ) ){
        prop = err.message.match( /'(.*?)'/ )[1];
        obj['wasundefined'] = {}
        obj['wasundefined'][prop] = "my value";
    }
}
```

This works because the error message for TypeError follows the pattern: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of undefined`

Comment: Good god, I guess my coffee didn't kick in yet...
Thx for this, it quite obviously is the way to go.

Comment: He doesn't want to report the error, he wants it to use a default value instead of signalling an error.

Comment: @Barmar, couldn'T I tell the catch block to return my empty string?

Comment: You would have to put that around EVERY use of the variable.

Comment: @SebastienD. If it's in a function, yes, you can return.  If you just want to set a variable to an empty string, yes, you can do that too in the catch block.  Barmar is being dramatic.

Comment: @CalvinFroedge Can you show how you would use this effectively to do what he wants? How would it fit into a block of code that's using all the properties?

Comment: @Barmar It's possible.  Hold on just a minute while I code that.

Comment: @Barmar Added example

Comment: OK, you add the default value to the object, but the code that tried to access it has already executed. It won't be restarted with the new value.

Comment: @Barmar Edited, tested

Comment: @SebastienD. Not if you're doing it on the string TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of undefined.  You could also split on ' and pull out the middle entry, ie err.message.split("'")[1]